# Replacing local directory with docker container directory

Tags: docker

We can copy the content of a directory from local to docker container using below command:

```
  docker cp /directory_path/. container_name:/destination_path/
```

But it don't replace the content of destination directory with local directory. The content inside destination directory still there. How can I replace the content of destination directory with my local directory.

Comment: try container_id instead of container_name.

Comment: Can you give more details so we can help you ? what's the images or container and show us what happened when you go into the container after the cp, because i made this work everytime...

Comment: I have a container name BackupC and I have a directory name mariabackup in my local machine, which contains mariadb backup. Now I want to restore this backup inside mariadb docker container BackupC. For that I need to empty directory /var/lib/mysql inside container and add content of mariabackup directory(which is in my local) to the /var/lib/mysql of docker container. I need this process to add in a script.  So, I was applying command docker cp /root/mariabackup/. BackupC:/var/lib/mysql/ . But still the original content in /var/lib/mysql exists.

Answer (score 0):

use `docker exec` to inject a command in the container, like deleting the files

```
  docker exec -ti my_container "rm -r /folder "
```

or

```
  docker exec -ti my_container /bin/bash
```

to access the shell and execute commands in the container, or access the container from the start

```
  docker run -it my_image /bin/bash
```

this way you can access the files and delete them.